# how to refactor form input map without unfocus on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that renders dynamiclly as a List of inputs like so

```
arrState.map((obj,index)=>{
    return(
       <input type="text" value={obj} onChange{(e) => stateHandler(e,index)}<input/>
    )
})
```

this works perfectly however only if I run it in the main return of the form however I want to clean my code up and make a seperate object for this section of the form, when I do this it still works but when I change the value the input unfocuses, How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind if you create a jsx function that is outside of the scope of the form and just pass the state and stateHandler as props it works, just if anyone needs it this was my solution

```
function InputMap({stateHandler, arrState}){
    arrState.map((obj,index)=>{
       return(
           <input type="text" value={obj} onChange={(e) => stateHandler(e,index)}>

           </input>
    )
})
}
function Form(){
    const [state, setState] = useState([])
    function stateHandler(e,index){
        // state handler
        let temp = [...state]
        temp[index] = e.target.value
        setState(temp)
    }
    return(
     <Form>
        <InputMap stateHandler={stateHandler, state}/>
     </Form>
)

}
```